# Not getting out of the loop

Tags: c++, loops

I am using this program to implement Mono alphabetic cipher. The problem i am getting is when i input plain text it doesn't get out of the loop when condition is met which is pressing the enter key.Here is my code.

```
int main()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Enter the plain text you want to encrypt";
    k = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        ch = getche();
        if(ch == '\n')
        {

            break; // here is the problem program not getting out of the loop
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] == ch)
            {
                ch = key[i];
            }
        }
        string[k] = ch;
        k++;
    }
    for(i = 0;i < k; i++)
    {
        cout << string[i];
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the break get hit or no? If not, does getche capture the newline character?

Comment: @devshorts That's the problem it's not getting newline character.

Comment: By any chance are you having this issue on a Widnows machine?

Comment: try '\r' instead of '\n'

Comment: @Yarneo already tried but not working.

Comment: What you should do is `cout` the character code returned by `getche`. When you hit enter, you'll see the first code generated by that key; break when you receive that code and everything will probably be OK.

Comment: Don't tag code as C and C++ just for fun. Use whichever tag is for the language you're using, in this case C++.

Comment: Do you need to clear the screen before each program activation?  This may remove some good history information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the problem is probably the fact that `getche()` (unlike `getchar()`) just returns the first character when there are more then one inputed and you are on windows (othewise you wouldn't use `cls`) then the EOL is encoded with `\r\n`.

What happens is that `getche()` returns `\r` so your break is never actually executed. You should change it to `getchar()` even because getche is a non standard function.

You can even try to look for `\r` instead that `\n` in your situation but I guess the `\n` would remain in the buffer causing problems if you need to fetch any additional input later (not sure about it).

Comment: Shouldn't it get `\n` after the `\r` though?

Comment: It should with `getchar`, it doesn't actually do it with `getche`.

Comment: Ahh, you just beat me to it. `getche` is apparently part of `conio.h`, which is some old school MSDOS code and as such shouldn't really be used anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Relying on old C libraries in C++ is yucky.  Consider this alternative:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; // haters gonna hate

char transform(char c) // replace with whatever you have
{
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') return ((c - 'a') + 13) % 26 + 'a';
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') return ((c - 'A') + 13) % 26 + 'A';
    else return c;
}

int main()
{
    // system("cls"); // ideone doesn't like cls because it isnt windows
    string outstring = "";
    char ch;
    cout << "Enter the plain text you want to encrypt: ";
    while(1)
    {
        cin >> noskipws >> ch;
        if(ch == '\n' || !cin) break;
        cout << (int) ch << " ";
        outstring.append(1, transform(ch));
    }
    cout << outstring << endl;
    cin >> ch;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like the fallowing which uses standard C++ I/O.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// you will need to fill out this table.
char arr[] = {'Z', 'Y', 'X'};
char key[] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string sInput;
    char   sOutput[128];
    int k;

    cout << "\n\nEnter the plain text you want to encrypt\n";
    cin >> sInput;

    for (k = 0; k < sInput.length(); k++) {
        char ch = sInput[k];

        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] == ch)
            {
                ch = key[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        sOutput[k] = ch;
    }
    sOutput[k] = 0;
    cout << sOutput;

    cout << "\n\nPause.  Enter junk and press Enter to complete.\n";
    cin >> sOutput[0];

    return 0;
}
```